# Dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 - Lost ability to boot from USB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

Good Morning,

I recently set up my Asus Windows 8.1 laptop to be a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04.  I have successfully created a dual boot system using Grub2 as my bootloader.

The problem is this:  when recently trying to boot from USB to run a LiveCD USB Linux distro, I have lost the ability to boot from USB.  The option does not show up in Grub2, I have ran the "sudo update-grub" command in Ubuntu and still the option isn't available.

Furthermore, when booting to the UEFI screen from Win8 [Advanced startup options > restart] when going to the usual screen to boot from a USB drive (how I installed Ubuntu in the first place) the option to boot from my USB is missing.  I only see two options: Ubuntu and Ubuntu.

Now both my Win 8.1 and Ubuntu are working fine but I would like to resolve this issue in case I ever need to boot from USB for recovery purposes.  But also I would really like to use this LiveCD and try out a new distro of Linux and I am unable to do so.

Has anyone experienced this before or have any tips to restore the ability to boot from USB from either Grub2 or UEFI, or both?

Thank you in advance!!!

Additional info - I work in IT and am pretty familiar with both Linux and Windows systems.  As this is my first PC with UEFI and not traditional BIOS, I am unfamiliar with this area.

Comment: What are the immediate options available when you startup your PC i.e., F2 or F10 or F12 or Esc or Del or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can get to the firmware's boot manager via a function key, as Raphael implies. If that list is missing the USB option, though, it could be that the USB drive you're using is missing the necessary boot files; or maybe the firmware has flaked out and permanently removed the USB boot option. If the latter, you might be able to get it back by fiddling with options in the firmware setup utility. (Sorry, I can't be more specific; unfortunately there's so little standardization in EFIs that it's impossible to point to a specific option without knowledge of the specific EFI in question.) In a worst-case scenario, restoring the firmware's defaults might do the trick -- but that might also render the system unable to boot Ubuntu.

Another option is to install my [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Once it's installed, it should detect EFI-bootable USB flash drives automatically -- although you may need to hit Esc to get it to scan them if they're slow to register. Ordinarily I recommend trying rEFInd from a USB flash drive or CD-R before installing it, but that's not exactly possible for you, so you'd have to jump straight to installing it via the Debian package or PPA.